# Customising Google+ Comment Count

Tags: google-plus

Google+ offer a comments option for websites. They also offer a comments counter like so:

When implementing this, it simply outputs "xx comments". This outputs as an iframe with styling stripped out. I want to keep the styling of the rest of my site, and also want to remove the word "comments" only to show the comment number. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the "comments option for websites" that you're using, please?

Comment: http://css.dzone.com/articles/add-google-comments-your-site

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to style the content of an iframe, but you can crop the visible text inside using CSS: `iframe { width: 14px; }`